# How to render component according the object returned by mapstatetoprops?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new in React.

**Scenerio:**

Redux State has : X, Y, Z objects:

```
    class A {
          render(){...}
        }

    mapstatetoprops(){
        return { X: x1}
    }

connect(mapstatetoprops)(A)
```

I read somewhere, when redux state is changed in X, Y or Z,  connect calls mapstatetoprops which rerenders the component A.

However, I want to rerender A only when X is changed. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

> I read somewhere, when redux state is changed in X, Y or Z, connect
>   calls mapstatetoprops which rerenders the component A.

This statement is partially true. A change in Redux state will trigger a call to `mapStateToProps()` (assuminging it's not a [deep-nested state change](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html#updating-nested-objects)). However, `render()` is only called if `props` or state is modified through `setState()` ([Link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating)).

Therefore, if your Redux state changes, `render()` will only be called depending on what action you take in `mapStateToProps()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best source which explain your Problem

Check Official Docs for More information https://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html

Why isn't my component re-rendering, or my mapStateToProps running?
Accidentally mutating or modifying your state directly is by far the most common reason why components do not re-render after an action has been dispatched. Redux expects that your reducers will update their state “immutably”, which effectively means always making copies of your data, and applying your changes to the copies. If you return the same object from a reducer, Redux assumes that nothing has been changed, even if you made changes to its contents. Similarly, React Redux tries to improve performance by doing shallow equality reference checks on incoming props in shouldComponentUpdate, and if all references are the same, shouldComponentUpdate returns false to skip actually updating your original component.

It's important to remember that whenever you update a nested value, you must also return new copies of anything above it in your state tree. If you have state.a.b.c.d, and you want to make an update to d, you would also need to return new copies of c, b, a, and state. This state tree mutation diagram demonstrates how a change deep in a tree requires changes all the way up.

Note that “updating data immutably” does not mean that you must use Immutable.js, although that is certainly an option. You can do immutable updates to plain JS objects and arrays using several different approaches:

Copying objects using functions like Object.assign() or _.extend(), and array functions such as slice() and concat()
The array spread operator in ES6, and the similar object spread operator that is proposed for a future version of JavaScript
Utility libraries that wrap immutable update logic into simpler functions